# Buck converter vs LDO

Tags: buck, ldo

I have a simple STM32 MCU board design that will be sleeping most of the time, waking every 30 minutes to take some measurements (which take about 20 seconds max), and then going back to sleep. It must run without intervention for 4 years (in the ground). Our sleep current usage is in the nAmps. I'm curious whether I am better off with a buck converter going from 6V -> 3.3V or use an LDO.  I realize the LDO is not as efficient and every mA counts so I am leaning toward a buck converter but wonder what others think.

Comment: Is this going to be battery powered?  And if so, does no intervention over 4 years mean no battery replacement in that time?  And what's going to wake the MCU up every 30 mins?

Comment: 6V to 3.3V is half your energy wasted. You need to compare that against the quiescent consumption of your buck. Not sure where you are getting 6V though. Seems needlessly high if energy is a concern and you do not mention sleeping anything that requires 5V which implies it does not exist and therefore 6V is not actually required or you it does but don't care about power.

Comment: Have you added up the mA-hrs (related to energy) for the two approaches, with a ~1.1% duty factor?  While, as DKNguyen said, the LDO will be at most 50% efficient, with a 1.1% duty cycle, that may not come to much in the grand scheme of things.

Comment: It is using 4 AA batteries to get to 6V.  I could reduce that to 3 AA to 4.5V?  The MCU uses enough power to drive an RTC which is set to cause the MCU to wake every 30 minutes.  And correct, the batteries cannot be replaced during this 4 year period.
I was considering the MP2331H buck converter

Comment: Yeah, if you don't need to regulate down 6V to something between 3.3V and 5V, it is a bit pointless. If you use a buck it can convert that extra voltage. If you use an LDO that's just wasted battery.  If you want to use 4AA batteries, you're better of using 6 of them in series groups of 3 in parallel with each other for twice the energy with less excess voltage of it being burned off  as heat if you use an LDO.

Comment: In this type of scenario, a LDO can be *more* efficient than a switcher. See https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/229926/how-to-efficiently-power-wireless-sensor-node-from-a-9v-battery/230076#230076

Comment: The [MP2331H](https://www.monolithicpower.com/en/documentview/productdocument/index/version/2/document_type/Datasheet/lang/en/sku/MP2331H/) has a quiescent current of 200 µA.  That's 1700 mAh in one year.  I think that'd drain your batteries too fast.

Comment: Are AAs, presumably Alkalines, okay buried in the ground for that long? Given their mAh and temperature changes?

Comment: Explain **why** you use 6 V batteries but then regulate down to 3.3 V. I am asking since many MCUs can work with voltages down to 1.8 V. So two 1.5 V cells in series (3V) will give you very good battery life already.

Comment: Is there any tradeoff in the fact that as the batteries start to deplete over 4 years that the 6V might actually drop to 5V still well within margin to get to my desired 3.3V but if I start with 3 in series at 4.5V and they deplete to say 3.5V now I'm really close to not being able to deliver the 3.3V needed?

Comment: You have something in the circuit that *requires* 3.3V for measurement purposes?

Comment: Explain why you have to have 3.3 V. The MCU will work at lower voltages just fine. I made a MCU based device that runs from 2 AA cells, it runs for years on a single set of batteries. No LDO needed. Optimum battery usage. Batteries will be less than 1 V each before I need to replace them.

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie. The MCU we are using requires 3.3V so I would at least need to go to 3 AA and bring it down to 3.3V.  And yes DKNuyen we have had AA buried in a water-tight enclosure for several years now without issue.

Comment: [The LM3671](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm3671.pdf) has a quiescent current of 16 µA.  Run it on 4.5V (three AA in series) and it'll only waste 140mAh per year.

Comment: *The MCU we are using requires 3.3V* No it doesn't. it will work on 2.5 V also. Now prove me wrong by showing me a link to the **datasheet** where it says that that MCU needs 3.3 V. I ask because the requires supply is never 3.3 V, it is like 3.3 V typical and 3..0 V minimum and 5.5 V maximum for example.

Comment: You may right @Bimpelrekkie.  The MCU we are using is actually a SiP that does both Sigfox and LoRa radio transmissions. STM32WL

Comment: Thanks @JRE. I'll definitely look more into the LM3671. And Adafruit has them on breakout boards so I can test them here in the lab.  Nice :-)

Comment: After re-reading the datasheet @Bimpelrekkie. You are correct, it actually says 1.8 - 3.6V. I will need to check with our STM FAE to see if we run at 1.8 will have an adverse effect on power output of the Lora TX

Comment: Some RF modules indeed require 3.3 V, they're more "picky" than an MCU. I also strongly advise to make a spreadsheet with the current consumption of each block/module, combine that with their Duty cycle (how long they're on) and you'll get **average** current consumption. From that you can estimate battery life but also an indication of where most energy goes.

Comment: So I just got confirmation that the output of the TX Lora signal will in fact be affected if we drop to 1.8V so I need to stay at 3.3V.  And yes, @Bimpelrekkie I have that spreadsheet under construction. :-)

Comment: You might be better off choosing a battery voltage that allows running the micro unregulated from the battery. Then parallel cells instead of series. If the voltage is too wimpy for your radio, perhaps a synchronous boost converter, or a charge pump, to boost voltage, that would be enabled only when transmitting. That would be OK only if total energy use in sleep is higher than what the radio uses, so the conversion loss would occur on the radio instead of occuring on the micro.

Comment: Likewise you could use a higher voltage battery, a micropower LDO for the microcontroller, used only in sleep mode, and a buck that is enabled only when it wakes up and makes a burst. That could result in less power use than a micropower buck. Unless you find a micropower buck that fits the bill, of course.

Comment: @bobflux Very interesting option. Once I get all my spreadsheet elements worked out with timings, etc, I'll see if something with that additional complexity would be advantageous

Comment: On the other hand: https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tps62840.pdf and https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/ADP5300.pdf -- the TI chip has over 70% efficiency at Vin=4V, Vout=3V3, 0.5µA current so it's almost as good as a LDO... who wins really depends on how your power budget is split between sleep and burst mode...

Comment: Awesome, thanks @bobflux I'll check that out as well